# What affect does taking a short term contract or part time job have on EI?

Tags: canada, termination, employment-insurance

I was recently terminated due to lack of work. I applied for EI. If I were to get a short term contract (like a couple months) or a part time job as an employee, how would this affect the EI?

I know this sounds strange but someone has a job prospect for me. It's for a rather unenjoyable job in a field that I am not interested in. If I work at it for a few weeks and hate it, can I go back on EI? Can I choose to work there part time and still be on EI?